# Time Zone format

Tags: time

When I find a time zone format like

"CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3"

what's the meaning of the three field? I understand the CET-1CEST but what about the last two M3.5.0 and M10.5.0/3?

I found this format in [this](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-ntp-timezones-daylight-saving/) tutorial for ESP32 NTP Time and in [this](https://gist.github.com/alwynallan/24d96091655391107939) list.

Comment: Were did you find that? You need to add more details.

Comment: @MCEmperor I edited the post with the links where I fount that time zone format

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you scroll a little down, you'll notice that such string is called a *timezone String* (at least in the article). After a quick search, I came across [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html), where the meaning of such string is found:

> *std offset dst [offset],start[/time],end[/time]*

For example,

> Here are some example `TZ` values, including the appropriate Daylight Saving Time and its dates of applicability. In North American Eastern Standard Time (EST) and Eastern Daylight Time (EDT), the normal offset from UTC is 5 hours; since this is west of the prime meridian, the sign is positive. Summer time begins on March’s second Sunday at 2:00am, and ends on November’s first Sunday at 2:00am.
>
> `EST+5EDT,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2`

So for `CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3`:

- The standard timezone is CET (Central European Time)
- The offset from UTC is −1
- The DST timezone is CEST (Central European Summer Time)
- DST starts at:

  - `3`: the third month of the year (March)
  - `5`: the *last*…
  - `0`: …Sunday of the month
  - (no *time* specifier, defaults to 2 AM)
- DST ends at:

  - `10`: the tenth month of the year (October)
  - `5`: the *last*…
  - `0`: …Sunday of the month
  - `3`: at 3 AM